# useState in a createHigherOrderComponent

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm quite new in react, so please be not to strong with me.

I'm trying to use useState in a HigherOrderComponent.
Unfortunately, the following code snippet gives the following error: `useState is not a function`
I don't know whether it's just the spelling of the useState declaration, or whether I'm wrong in a HigherOrderComponent anyway.

```
const { Fragment } = wp.element;
const { addFilter } = wp.hooks;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.editor;
const { CheckboxControl } = wp.components;
const { createHigherOrderComponent } = wp.compose;
const { useState } = wp.element;   

const withInspectorControls = createHigherOrderComponent( ( BlockEdit ) => {
        return ( props ) => {
            //const [ isChecked, setChecked ] = useState( true ); <-- Fails here, useState is not a function
            return (
                <Fragment>
                    <BlockEdit { ...props } /> 
                    <InspectorControls>
                        <CheckboxControl
                            heading="User"
                            label="Is author"
                            help="Is the user a author or not?"
                            checked={ isChecked } 
                            onChange={ setChecked }
                            />  
                    </InspectorControls>
                </Fragment>
    
            );
        };
    }, 'withInspectorControl' );
    
    addFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'wpse', withInspectorControls );
```

If someone might give me a tip, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: are you sure you imported it? `import React, {useState} from 'react'`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I think I did that correctly (I updated my snippet above).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with using React in Wordpress but can you try to add this code on top of your file?

```
const {
    element: {
        useState,
    },
} = wp;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I think I did that correctly (I updated my snippet above).

Comment: Are your react and react-dom versions the same?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused. I updated my Wordpress core from 5.5.2 to 5.5.3 - and now my code snippet from above works. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use it, because HigherOrderComponent returns a  [React class component](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) and you cannot use react hooks inside a Class component so, you need to follow the lifecyclye for it. Here [create createHigherOrderComponent examples](https://javascript.hotexamples.com/es/examples/%40wordpress.element/-/createHigherOrderComponent/javascript-createhigherordercomponent-function-examples.html) you can see several examples how use it.

Something like this worked for me, hope it helps!

```
     const withCoverSettingsControl = createHigherOrderComponent((BlockEdit) => {
      return class CoverExtented extends Component {
        /** @inheritdoc */
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {
              newState: false
          }
          this.switchState = this.switchState.bind(this)
        }

        switchState() {
           this.setState({ newState: true })
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          console.log('init comp....')
        }
    
        render() {
          const { attributes, setAttributes } = this.props
          console.log('comp render....')
    
          return (
            <Fragment>
              <BlockEdit {...this.props} />
            </Fragment>
          )
        }
      }
    }, 'withCoverSettingsControl')
    
    addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'extend-core-cover', withCoverSettingsControl)
```